# 2D Discrete Fourier Transform and Inverse DFT

Tags: image, delphi, pascal, lazarus, dft

I am currently implementing 2D DFT and IDFT for images, and the response of my IDFT is not the same from the original image. It is intriguing because the generated image looks inverted. I don't know if I am considering all the terms. Maybe I would have to work with the phase, but I don't know how.
Here is my code for DFT

```
var
i, j, k, M, N, u, v, x, y:integer; 
aux: extended; 
Real, Imaginario, Mag, IMag, Vagxy:TMatriz; 
Vag:TVetorE;
 
M:=16; 
N:=16; 
SetLength(Mag, M, N); //Magnitudes
ZeraMatriz(Mag, M, N);
SetLength(Real, M, N);
SetLength(Imaginario, M, N);
aux:=2*pi;
for u:=0 to M-1 do
    for v:=0 to N-1 do
        begin
             ZeraMatriz(Real, M, N);
             ZeraMatriz(Imaginario, M, N);
             for x:=0 to M-1 do  
                 for y:=0 to N-1 do  
                    begin
                         Real[u,v]:=Real[u,v]+(Vagxy[x,y]*cos(aux*(((u*x)/M)+(v*y)/N)));
                         Imaginario[u,v]:=Imaginario[u,v]-(Vagxy[x,y]*sin(aux*(((u*x)/M)+(v*y)/N)));
                         //Form1.Memo.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Form1.Memo.Lines.Count)+'     Vag:  '+FloattoStr(Vagxy[x,y])+ 'x'+ InttoStr(x)+ 'y'+ InttoStr(y));
                    end;
              Mag[u,v]:=sqrt(Power(Real[u,v],2)+Power(Imaginario[u,v],2));
              //Form1.Memo.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Form1.Memo.Lines.Count)+'     Mag:  '+FloattoStr(Mag[u,v]));
        end;
```

And here is my code for IDFT

```
M:=16; 
N:=16; 
aux:=2*pi;
SetLength(IMag, M, N);
ZeraMatriz(IMag, M, N);
SetLength(Real, M, N);
SetLength(Imaginario, M, N);
for x:=0 to M-1 do
    for y:=0 to N-1 do
        begin
             ZeraMatriz(Real, M, N);
             ZeraMatriz(Imaginario, M, N);
             for u:=0 to M-1 do  
                 for v:=0 to N-1 do  
                    begin
                         Real[x,y]:=Real[x,y]+(Mag[u,v]*cos(aux*(((u*x)/M)+(v*y)/N)));
                         Imaginario[x,y]:=Imaginario[x,y]+(Mag[u,v]*sin(aux*(((u*x)/M)+(v*y)/N)));
                    end;
             IMag[x,y]:=(sqrt(Power(Real[x,y],2)+Power(Imaginario[x,y],2)))/(M*N);
        end;

// shows image
k:=0;
for y := 0 to N-1 do
    for x := 0 to M-1 do
        begin
             Vag[k]:=IMag[x,y];
             k:=k+1;
        end;
```

I want to understand if my code is correct and if not I want to know where. I have no idea why I can't get back the original image after performing IDFT on the DFTed image.

Comment: Please include variable declarations in your code.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry... i, j, k, M, N, u, v, x, y:integer;
    aux: extended;
    Real, Imaginario, Mag, IMag, Vagxy:TMatriz;
    Vag:TVetorE; (Vag is the vector which saves the coordinates "z" of each node of the mash and it is part of something bigger of the code so I created the "Vagxy" to represent the "z" values of the correspondent x and y. At the end of the code I need to return to Vag because it is how we plot the image.

Comment: You can edit your question to add these declarations.